# What risks are suited for a Dangerous survivor in the Shotgun Diaries?

Tags: the-shotgun-diaries

When does the Dangerous survivor get to use his ability? Since weapons grant bonus dice by default, what risks are suited for a Dangerous survivor?

Combating humans doesn't seem applicable, because no dice are rolled if no zombies are present. Although it would seem like an appropriate use.

Teaching others how to use a gun? Only when zombies are on the survivors' heels, maybe.

Any takes on this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have misunderstood the rule on page 6 under tools and weapons.
The +2 is not referring to +2 dice for a gun, but is instead referring to +2 for the success criteria. See Below.

Form Rule book:

---

If any of your dice rolls a 6, you get to say what happens to your Survivor. If none of your dice rolls a 6, the Narrator says what happens to your Survivor.

The Dangerous Survivor
The Dangerous Survivor has been trained with weapons. He’s a cop or a
soldier or just a gun nut. The Dangerous Survivor always rolls at least four
dice for any risk involving weapons.

A tool or weapon that gives you a +2 turns a 4, 5 into a 6, giving you a success

Hand weapons +1, Firearms +2

---

So a fast survivor with a gun, I would suggest a house rule that he gets to roll 1 die basic for using a gun. So he wants to get a 4,5,6 on a single die to Kill Zombies, as we all know you only roll dice if you are Killing Zombies.

In contrast a Dangerous survivor with a gun could be rolling 4 or more dice looking for success on 4,5, or 6 (or potentially successes) when killing zombies as this is using a weapon.

Comment: While I explained myself unclearly (I perfectly agree about the +1/+2 for weapons), your response is not addressing the core of my issue.
I was wondering about which types of actions are specific to a Dangerous character? For example, there are plenty of uses for a Clever character (generators, radios, security, car repairs, ...). However, the only ones I can come up with for a Dangerous character are (1) holding off zombies or (2) rushing through zombie hordes towards a place or (3) fighting other humans. But per the rules, you should never roll for fighting zombies directly, or humans.